# React useEffect executes every time the state is updated

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, frontend

In my React component I have the following code (I'm gonna exclude the return statement because it's not relevant for this case):

```
const App = () => {

let webSocket = new WebSocket(WS_URL);

  const [image, setImage] = useState({});
  const [bannerName, setBannerName] = useState('');
  const [bannerId, setBannerId] = useState(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    webSocket.onopen = (evt) => {
      console.log('On open web socket: ', evt);
    }
    
    webSocket.onmessage = (evt) => {
      console.log('SERVER DATA: ', evt.data);
    }

    console.log('Ready state: ', webSocket.readyState);
  }, []);

const updateImage = (evt) => {
    setImage(evt.target.files[0]);
  }

  const updateBannerName = (evt) => {
    setBannerName(evt.target.value);
  }

const updateBannerID = (evt) => {
    setBannerId(Number(evt.target.value));
  }
}
```

As I understand, if I use the `useEffect()` hook with an empty dependency array, it should be executed just once (it should work like a `componentDidMount` when using class components).

The problem is that it's being executed every time I update the state properties. Does anyone know what am I missing here?

Thank you!

Comment: is every console.log printed out every time or only specific ones?

Comment: Not sure what happens, but I do note that you creat a new WebSocket every time the App component code runs (and that is every time you update a state variable for example). Do you really mean to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do note that you create a new WebSocket every time the App component code runs (and that is every time you update a state variable for example). Do you really mean to do this?

Otherwise change your code so that the WebSocket is only created once.